# Convert a vector of integers to a vector of strings

Tags: r

`toString` seems to convert a whole vector to a single string -

```
toString(c(1,2))
[1] "1, 2"
```

how does one map the string conversion over each element; i.e. for the above example, to obtain `("1", "2")` ?

Comment: Try `as.character()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> as.character(c(1,2))
[1] "1" "2"
```

Is the output I get from the R-console.

Comment: Also, I wanted to add... `toString(c(1,2))` will convert the vector into a single string "1, 2". With `as.character(c(1,2))` this will convert the individual elements of the vector c(1,2).

Answer (score 1):

Since the result is a character vector with a single element, the strategy of using `as.character` will have no effect. Need to use `scan`:

```
> scan(text = toString(0:11),  sep="," )
Read 12 items
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Then you can use `as.character` if that is needed:

```
> res <- scan(text = toString(0:11),  sep="," )
Read 12 items
> as.character(res)
 [1] "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11"
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the OP.  I think their *starting* value was `c(1,2)` (or `0:11` in your example), not `toString(c(1,2))` ...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `paste0` since it's shorter and (from what I can tell) accomplishes the same thing as `as.character`:

```
> paste0(1:2)
[1] "1" "2"

> identical(paste0(1:2),as.character(1:2))
[1] TRUE
```